# Not able to get a normal jupyter notebook file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting a python project and when I'm opening a jupyter notebook in the directory I'm getting the following file. Normally there are other tabs such as kernel. Additionally I'm not able to run code using control + shift.

[image]

Comment: You opened a regular Python file (`.py`), not an iPython notebook (`.ipynb`)

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebooks are the files with extension `.ipynb` not with the extension `.py` which you are opening right now (`main.py`).

Look for a file with `.ipynb` extension and open it, it will run fine.